# windeployqt doesn't deploy qwindowsd.dll for a debug application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use `windeployqt.exe` (Qt 5.13.2) to deploy dlls for a debug application generated by CMake 3.16. All the dlls are deployed correctly except for the platform plugin dll, which deploys `qwindows.dll` instead of `qwindowsd.dll` and results in the following error when I try to run the executable:

> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.

So far, I've tried:

- Specifying `--debug` on the `windeployqt` command line. That failed because `Qt5Coredd.dll` could not be found (note the double d's).
- Verifying that no Qt plugin related environment variables are set.
- Checked `PATH` to make sure it doesn't contain any folder with a `platforms` directory.

If I copy `qwindowsd.dll` manually, everything works fine. However I'd really like to figure out what I'm doing wrong with `windeployqt`.

Comment: If you add verbose flag do you get any additional information?

Comment: @deW1 with level 2 enabled I could see that it was looking for a mix of release and debug libraries, but couldn't tell why

Comment: Does it work when you create a new default Widgets Application -> Select CMake -> build -> run windeployqt TestWidgets.exe (for example). I've had 5.13.1 laying around works fine there.

Comment: I’ve also noticed issues like this, all deployed plugins were in release mode. I think deploying debug builds isn’t really supported (the use cases are limited I think because there are legal restrictions to distributing the MSVC debug runtimes IIRC). Worth creating a minimal example and a bug report, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a known problem that Qt have dragged their heels on fixing, but I figured out a workaround in CMake - this works for both the Ninja generator/Visual Studio's built in CMake support as well as the regular Visual Studio solution generator

```
# Split windeployqt into 2 parts to fix issue with deploying debug plugins
add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${QT_PATH}/bin/windeployqt --compiler-runtime --no-plugins ${MY_APP_EXE})
if (CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Ninja")
    # Ninja is a single-config generator so we can use CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to generate different commands
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
        add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${QT_PATH}/bin/windeployqt --debug --no-compiler-runtime --no-translations --no-libraries ${MY_APP_EXE})
    else()
        add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${QT_PATH}/bin/windeployqt --release --no-compiler-runtime --no-translations --no-libraries ${MY_APP_EXE})
    endif()
else()
    # if in MSVC we have to check the configuration at runtime instead of generating different commands
    add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp POST_BUILD
        COMMAND cmd.exe /c if "$(Configuration)" == "Debug" ${QT_PATH}/bin/windeployqt --debug --no-compiler-runtime --no-translations --no-libraries ${MY_APP_EXE})
    add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp POST_BUILD
        COMMAND cmd.exe /c if not "$(Configuration)" == "Debug" ${QT_PATH}/bin/windeployqt --release --no-compiler-runtime --no-translations --no-libraries ${MY_APP_EXE})
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself when using Conan 2.0 and the *CMakeToolchain* and *CMakeDeps* generators. I was running `conan install .. --output-folder=. -b missing -s build_type=Debug` and used `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`. With the default Conan profile, this will create an executable in debug mode **that is linked against the *release* VC runtime.**

To fix this, you can either create a new profile for debug builds where you specify `compiler.runtime_type=Debug` or run `conan install` with `-s compiler.runtime_type=Debug`.