# How to copy Qt dll's using windeploy

Tags: qt, windeployqt

I am writing an Qt application and trying to automate Qt dll's deployment automattic via QWindeploy and the code looks as following:

```
########## QT DEPLOYMENT ##########
get_target_property(_qmake_executable Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)
get_filename_component(_qt_bin_dir "${_qmake_executable}" DIRECTORY)
find_program(WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE windeployqt HINTS "${_qt_bin_dir}")
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE} --no-compiler-runtime ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/${PROJECT_NAME}.exe)")
##########
```

With the above code qwindowsd.dll is not copied during debug mode, but release mode works quite well. I have even tried running windeploy via CMD but gives the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYKhz.png)

Somehow it is looking for wrong dll (QtCoredd.dll).

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I think that’s just broken and deserves a bug report in the Qt JIRA. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828611/windeployqt-doesnt-deploy-qwindowsd-dll-for-a-debug-application

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Thanky you for the link and yea i will report the bug. I have built another application and wondering how come does it work for this app.